# Add the product category to Cross sells product title in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I want to add the Category Name to the end of Cross sell items that appear while browsing shopping cart. But, I can't figure out the hook for this, so not sure how to approach with a function.

Is there a hook for Cross sell items? I've changed the names of products in the cart no issue with the woocommerce_cart_item_name hook, so hoping to do the same with a function for Cross sell items.

Is it doable? Any track on this is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note:** Upsells are in single product pages. In cart page they are Cross-sells.

You can simply use the following:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'cross_sells_loop_product_title', 10 );
function cross_sells_loop_product_title() {
    $title = get_the_title();

    if( is_cart() ) {
        $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', ['fields' => 'names'] );
        $title .=  ' - ' . reset( $product_categories );
    }
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . $title . '</h2>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That almost worked. But, it is instead putting the correct h2 title after the old title:

100% Stonewashed French Linen
100% Stonewashed French Linen - Flat Sheet

Could it be due to the priority setting?

Also, how do I generate the correct url to get to the product? The original title still has a working URL, while the new/correct title that comes right after is missing any way to link it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. But you will still see the original title still there. So, in the screenshot under the Thumbnail you will see a title link "100% Stonewashed French Linen". This is the title I want to replace. But instead of replacement, after it comes "100% Stonewashed French Linen - Flat Sheet". That is the correct updated title, so the first title should no longer exist. Right now the thumbnail product has two titles on the page, when should only have the second.

Comment: You are right. In the themes own woocommerce folder, there is a file content-product.php that is already removing the action and adding: `<h3><a class="product-title-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>`

Comment: That is so close! It  is outputting `<h3><a class="product-title-link meme" href="https://example.com">100% Stonewashed French Linen</a></h3>
- Flat Sheet` It's putting the category outside the_title() function and therefore outside the <h3> tag.

Comment: I should have clarified that I used the functions.php solution for the child theme.

Comment: This actually fixed the issue, but broke the upper menu for some reason: `function add_categories_to_the_title($title,$id) {
    if ( is_cart() ) {  
        $product_categories = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_id(), 'product_cat', ['fields' => 'names'] );
            //$title = get_the_title();
            $title .= ' - ' . reset( $product_categories );
    }

    echo $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_categories_to_the_title', 11);`

Comment: Hello! Yes, It seems impossible to fix by function alone -- in my theme's case -- and have to edit the actual content-single.php file to correct. How do I accept the answer?